# Find coordinate at minimum distance from list of coordinates

Tags: java, algorithm, spatial

I have a list of coordinates in 2D space (x<sub>i</sub>, y<sub>i</sub>). How can I find a coordinate (X, Y) such that the distance between it and the other given coordinates is minimum? Is there a mathematical formula to solve for (X, Y)?

Let me give an example..
Lets say i have list of co.ordinates (0,0);(1,0);(0,1);(-1,0);(0,-1);
Now i have to findout possible co.ordinate(s)(one or many) such that the resulting co.ordinate is at minimun distance from all the points. in this case (0,0).

As Voo said,This is my requirement :
**Find a point that minimizes the sum of the distances to the points in a given set**

Comment: @Voo: Oh, yes, that's possible.  The OP hasn't mentioned "sum", but I think you could be right.  Let's hope they clarify...

Comment: TFool, please clarify exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: @Oli I think we should stop deleting posts/comments, otherwise this is getting quite complicated ;) (I wouldn't have deleted your answer though, it was a good answer for one possible interpretation after all) To sum up the conversation: There are two ways to interpret the question: Find the point in the given set that has a minimum distance to a given point. Or: Find a point that minimizes the sum of the distances to the points in a given set.

Comment: @voo: yes u r correct.. This is my requirement : **Find a point that minimizes the sum of the distances to the points in a given set**

Answer (score 2):

**Assuming you're asking for the closest candidate to a given point**

You are asking about [*nearest neighbour searches*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search).

The simplest approach is simply too loop over every candidate coordinate, compute the Euclidean distance (assuming you want a Euclidean metric), and track the minimum. Is that sufficient?

More complex (but potentially faster) approaches involve storing your candidate points in e.g. a [space-partitioning tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_partitioning), e.g. a quad-tree, or a kd-tree, or one of several other variants.

Answer (score 1):

```
public Coord2D minDistance(List<Coord2D> coordinates, Coord2D someCoord) {
   float minDistance = Float.MAX_VALUE;
   Coord2D result;
   for (Coord2D coord : coordinates) {
       float distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((coord.x - someCoord.x), 2) + (Math.pow((coord.y - someCoord.y), 2))
       if (distance < result) { 
           result = coord;
           minDistance = distance;
       }
   }

   return result;
}
```

Comment: If the list was large then you could improve performance by only doing a single sqrt outside the loop.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan you mean for the power calculation for someCoord (sqrt must be calculated per coordinate)

Comment: No, since sqrt is monotonic, you the point that minimises f(x) also minimises f(x)^2 so you can postpone the sqrt to the end.

Answer (score 1):

Requirement: Find a point that minimizes the sum of the distances to the points in a given set.

The point with the minimum euclidean distance sum to all other points, has:

x = mean average of all X in the set
 y = mean average of all Y in the set

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate distance between two points using euclidien distance formula: 
      squareroot((x1-X)²+(yi-Y)²) 
or you can use manhattan formula: 
      |yi-Y|+|xi-X|.

Is this a pathfinding problem?